# I want to load a browser component and want to fire a URL

Tags: java, swing, jsp, jxbrowser

I want to load a browser component using swing.
below is my full requirement
I want to create a one desktop application that will load browser component and fire one URL so that user will get one jsp page that is deployed in another server.
I googled and found one code from below link but problem is jsp page is loaded without any CSS or like that we have applied while making jsp page

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-create-a-simple-browser-in-swing-3.html

I verified css is applied properly by firing URL in another browser.
I tried using jxbrowser api also but that is giving me licensing error.may be it is paid version(I am not sure)
Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider `java.awt.Desktop#browse()`.

Comment: I don't want to open a new browser.I want to load a browser in swing

Comment: Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cal load browser eclipse.swt.browser.Browser class 
check this url : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingBrowsertoloadawebsite.htm

Comment: For further guidance, please address @Niraj Thakar.